# SQL Server on azure virtual machines default instance

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-vm

We have two ways of provisioning SQL Server on an Azure virtual machine, one is creating the VM and then upload the binaries of SQL server and do the installation manually, the second one is using SQL Server on Azure virtual machines which provides images of the OS and the desired version on SQL Server.

The question applies to the second option. Is there a way to provision a SQL Server virtual machine on azure with a named instance or does it always install the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is there a way to provision a SQL Server virtual machine on azure with a named instance or does it always install the default?**

Not with the pre-built images.

If you provision your own VM and use IaaS agent extension you can use named instance.

Can I install a second instance of SQL Server on the same VM? Can I change installed features of the default instance?

> Yes. The SQL Server installation media is located in a folder on the C
> drive. Run Setup.exe from that location to add new SQL Server
> instances or to change other installed features of SQL Server on the
> machine. Note that some features, such as Automated Backup, Automated
> Patching, and Azure Key Vault Integration, only operate against the
> default instance, or a named instance that was configured properly.

Can I use a named instance of SQL Server with the IaaS extension?

> Yes, if the named instance is the only instance on the SQL Server, and
> if the original default instance was uninstalled properly. If there is
> no default instance and there are multiple named instances on a single
> SQL Server VM, the SQL Server IaaS agent extension will fail to
> install.

Ref:

- [Frequently asked questions for SQL Server on Azure VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/frequently-asked-questions-faq)
- [Automate management tasks on Azure virtual machines by using the SQL Server IaaS Agent Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-server-iaas-agent-extension-automate-management)

Answer (score 0):

Build your own image exactly how you want it & then use that - Azure provides tools to make it easier :-

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/streamlining-your-image-building-process-with-azure-image-builder/

Comment: Thanks!  I will look this option